# Proving $Df(x) > q ≥ 0 \implies λ^∗(f(E)) ≥ qλ^∗(E)$

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Prove the following : Let $f$ be strictly increasing on $[a, b]$, and let $E \subset [a, b]$. If at each $x \in E$ there exists a derived number $Df(x) > q ≥ 0$, then $λ^∗(f(E)) ≥ qλ^∗(E)$. [Hint: Begin with an appropriate open set $G$ containing $f(E)$. Note that the set of discontinuities of $f$ is countable.]

A similar theorem exists in the text but for $Df(x) < p$ :

[image]

The problem that I cannot mimic the proof of the case $Df(x) < p$ for the case $Df(x) > q ≥ 0$ is that $λ(J_n(x_0))$ doesn't necessarily have limit zero if $λ(I_n(x_0))$ does, so the hint also is not very helpful. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, the case $q=0$ is trivial, since $λ^∗(f(E)) \geq 0 = 0 \cdot λ^∗(E)$. So we can assume $q> 0$.
Now, if $f$ is strictly incresing, then $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing.  If $Df(x) > q > 0$, then  $Df^{-1}(y) < 1/q$. Can you now adapt the proof of Lemma 7.1 to what you need, by taking  an appropriate open set $G$ containing $f(E)$ and using $f^{-1}$?

If you need, I will post a complete answer.